# Static resources not accessible in Jersey rest

Tags: regex, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am having problem accessing my static resources in `/project/resources/(css|js)/`. I was able to access `index.css` in my css folder, but no other. I tried to find the root cause, changed regex expressions and messed up everything. Now I am not able to access even `index.css` now. Please find details below -

**File structure -**

```
webapp
  |____ resources
  |       |____ css
  |       |____ js
  |
  |____ WEB-INF
          |____ jsp
```

**web.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
 see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>REST Web Application</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restui</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(resources/(css|js))|(WEB-INF/jsp)/*.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>REST Web Application</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I tried to find solutions on net but nothing was useful. Hoping for the useful solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you receive a 404 Not Found error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex` property should work if you are using Jersey 2.x.

I believe your static resources are only on resources folder.

Try this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
    <param-value>/resources/(css|js)/.*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Does adding more regex options confuse the app ? I am asking so that I can avoid adding redundant things for security as I did before..